# Google+ snippet not rendering image

Tags: google-plus, meta-tags

I have implemented google share functionality in my web app. I am facing a problem which is, when i share story over google, image not gets rendered. I have tested it on google webmaster tool where i can see url of image but no image with snippet

[here check Structured Data Testing Tool result](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fserver2008r2dns.cloudapp.net%2FJob%2FShareJob%3Fjob%3D5~OCSOXXIIYSVKGNW~10132)

here my meta tags are:

Is anything with meta tags?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/y7prp.png

Comment: Yeah its working now.